# Convert 2 HTML file output from SQL query into 1 main HTML output file in shell script

Tags: shell-script, html, sql, oracle-database

In shell script, I used 2 different SQL query & output of these 2 files in HTML format like `(eg- ab.html, cd.html)`. Shell script as ->

```
#/bin/ksh

ab=$(SQLPLUS -s <username>/<password>@DB <<EOF
set heading ON
set trimspool OFF
SET MARKUP HTML ON
set feedback off
spool ab.html
select col_1, col_2, col_3 from <tab>;
spool off;
exit;
EOF)

echo "$ab" > ab.html

----- DML operation perform

cd=$(SQLPLUS -s <username>/<password>@DB <<EOF
set heading ON
set trimspool OFF
SET MARKUP HTML ON
set feedback off
spool cd.html
select col_4 from <tab>;
spool off;
exit;
EOF)

echo "$cd" > cd.html

cat ab.html cd.html > output.html
exit 0
```

Then getting `output.html` file as ->

```
 ______________________________
| col_1     | col_2  |   col_3 |
| .....     | ...... |   ..... |
| .....     | ...... |   ..... |
|___________|________|_________|
 ______________________________              
|             col_4            |
|             ......           |
|______________________________|
```

But I want final `output.html` like col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4 column in one table like below ->

```
 ______________________________________
| col_1     | col_2  |   col_3  | col_4|
| .....     | ...... |   .....  | .....|
| .....     | ...... |   .....  | .....|
|___________|________|__________|______|
```

Could you please help me how to merge these 2 HTML file into one output HTML file so that we can able to see like above format.
I just draw HTML table as example but internal border always comes in HTML table, so please don't look HTML table format that I used.

Comment: Is the table of 1st query different from table of 2nd query? Is performing only one query that outputs the four columns a possibility?

Comment: In your scripts is redundant the redirection to the HTML files since the spool command already does that job.

Comment: @PauloTomé DML operation is also performing. SO the 2nd query will run after DML operation perform. So we can.t use all 4 columns in same query.

Answer (score -1):

Joining html content after the tag is not easy and recommended.
We could use SQL iteslf to generate the.

```
SELECT t1.owner, t1.object_id, t2.name
FROM (
   SELECT owner, object_id,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY owner) as rn
   FROM dba_objects where rownum < 10)  t1
FULL OUTER JOIN  (
   SELECT name, 
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name) as rn
   FROM v$database)  t2
ON t1.rn = t2.rn
```

We can use ROW_NUMBER function to create a calculated field that can be used to join the two tables together since we dont have anything in common and use  FULL OUTER JOIN.

Comment: (1) As you can see, [SE] doesn’t allow table markup (HTML).  It primarily uses Markdown with *very* limited HTML. (2) Please add a ***lot*** more explanation.  You are showing a table with three columns.  The OP already has that; how does your answer help?  Why are you doing a join between two tables?  Etc. … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.